# How to change float64 to double in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

The objective is to convert from `float64` to double.

However, using the `astype(np.double)` does not changed the array type.

```
numpy.random.seed(0)
arr=np.random.rand(32,30,30)
arr1=arr.astype(np.double)
print(f'arr:{arr.dtype} and arr1: {arr1.dtype}')
```

> arr:float64 and arr1: float64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
np.double is np.float64 # returns True
```

As you can see they are virtually the same

You can see that in the docs [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.double) where it is mentioned that `np.float64` is just an alias for `np.double`